# Javascript Function Problem

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I tend to write my javascript as big blocks of code without many variable or functions but have decided to clean up my act!  Below is an attempt at writing a cleaner version of a script that hides certain form elements depending on the value of a drop down box.

The script worked perfectly before I tried to tidy it up but now I cannot see where the problem is?  Could anyone advise me of any problems with my syntax here.  Apologies for the very specific post.

Thanks,

Rich

```
function hideTitle(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="none";
    };
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="inline";
    };
};

function hideSocMedLinks(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="none";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="none";
    };
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="block";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="inline";
    };
};

function hideWebLink(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.webLink.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("webtext").style.display="none";
    };
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.webLink.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("webtext").style.display="inline";
    };
};

function toggleFormElements(){
    if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "homePage"){
        hideTitle("true");
        hideSocMedLinks("true");
        hideWebLink("true");
    };
    else if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "socialMedia"){
        hideTitle("false");
        hideSocMedLinks("false");
        hideWebLink("true");
    };
    else if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "webDesign"){
        hideTitle("false");
        hideSocMedLinks("true");
        hideWebLink("false");
    };
};
```

Comment: So the basic problem is that it doesn't work, isn't?

Comment: Maybe some sample html code would help?

Comment: Posting an example in a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful.

Comment: It's been sorted below - apologies for the lack of a working example.

Comment: You should use booleans, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double equals (==) to test for equality. The single equals that is currently in your if statements will assign the value that you think you are testing for and evaluate to true. In other words, for almost all values of 'hide' the if will execute, not just the value "true".

```
function hideSocMedLinks(hide){
    if(hide == "true"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="none";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="none";
    }
    else if(hide == "false"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="block";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="inline";
    }
}
```

Comment: even better if you use triple equals! `===` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804005/whats-the-reason-to-use-instead-of-with-typeof-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You have semi-colons (`;`) after your if statements - that could be the cause of your syntax issues. See the arrows below:

```
function hideTitle(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="none";
    }; <----
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="inline";
    }; <----
};
```

Comment: That in conjunction with the == faux pas sorted it out a treat thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Removing the unnecessary semi-colons should solve the issue.

```
function hideTitle(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="none";
    }
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.title.style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("titleText").style.display="inline";
    }
}

function hideSocMedLinks(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="none";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="none";
    }
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.facebookLink.style.display="block";
        document.admin.twitterLink.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("fbtext").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("twittext").style.display="inline";
    }
}

function hideWebLink(hide){
    if(hide = "true"){
        document.admin.webLink.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("webtext").style.display="none";
    }
    else if(hide = "false"){
        document.admin.webLink.style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("webtext").style.display="inline";
    }
}

function toggleFormElements(){
    if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "homePage"){
        hideTitle("true");
        hideSocMedLinks("true");
        hideWebLink("true");
    }
    else if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "socialMedia"){
        hideTitle("false");
        hideSocMedLinks("false");
        hideWebLink("true");
    }
    else if(document.admin.pageType.options[document.admin.pageType.selectedIndex].value == "webDesign"){
        hideTitle("false");
        hideSocMedLinks("true");
        hideWebLink("false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put `;`s after code blocks.

In particular, the `;`s after your `if`s end the `if` blocks, causing the `else`s to be unattached.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after the closing `}` in all your `if / else` blocks. 
Also, are you passing the boolean value `true/false` to your function or are you passing the string `"true"/"false"`?

```
// This is incorrect
if (stuff) {
  // stuff
};
else if {
  // etc...
};

// Should be
if (stuff) {
  // stuff
}
else if {
  // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the semicolons (`;`) after the closing braces (`}`) before each `else` should be removed, but one other problem I can see is that you're using a single equals inside your `if` statements.  In Javascript a single equals sign will always attempt assign to the left hand side.  What you want for comparisons is double or triple equals (`==` or `===`).