# can js objects be reassigned dynamically to a different type?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

i wanted to know if js ws similar to php in the sense that I can reassign an object and it will work.  Ex:  Click 1 button and X = "5", Click other button and Y = new Array(4); X = Y;

I was unsure if js was just pointers and would allow this, or if there was some sort of typecast error.... as my default use is that of a string.  When they click the alternate button essentually, they are going to try to append to it or just convert it to an array.

Maybe an easy way around this is just to make it be an array from the getgo, and just reference 0 unless otherwise told.

Thoughts?

Comment: I feel as though this is not a good practice...

Comment: dynamic typing can be good http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122205/what-is-the-supposed-productivity-gain-of-dynamic-typing

Comment: you are correct.  I am modifying code that is in place using a JQUERY selector on a JS item, singular.  With that in mind, i need to impletemt a ctrl+click functionality to allow multiple items to be clicked.  Overall, this was the first solution option i was thinking to do to try to minimize the actual code manipulation.

Comment: @Fallenreaper a jQuery selector of one item has the same "type" as a jQuery selector of multiple items. So you're not doing something dirty if you use the same code to perform a process on multiple items that was intended to work on one item. That's the spirit of most jQuery plugins.

Comment: @SamuelRossille so if i just modify where my click events would be, and adjust code accordingly, I could make an array, and pass in the array and it would carry out the exact same thing? sweet.  Everything is done with jquery pretty much, i just have to edit the contents of this one object and in theory, everything would work.

Comment: I'm just saying that (for example) you can replace $("#id-of-my-single-item") with $(".class-of-my-multiple-items") or $(arrayOfHtmlElements) of $(element1, element2, ...) without trouble if everything you do with the resulting selector works transparently with multiple items (bind, click, mouseup, css, trigger, addClass, etc... are in this category). And that's all. Basically, you can see a jQuery selector as a list of elements, and what you call a "single" selector is a list of one item.

Comment: @SamuelRossille That is great to know... because my js array is infact an array of divs... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript syntax allows that. But it's not recomended to use this "feature" because it will make your code harder to understand.

Comment: security through obsecurity. ;)  haha.  Alright, great to know.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is loosely typed; any variable can be reassigned to any value at any time.

```
var X = 5;
X = [1,2,3];
X = {name: 'John', town: 'London'};
```

No problems here. However, like @SamuelRossille said, you probably want to steer clear of such code to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Its called dynamic typing and can have [many benefits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122212/2297).

The [tripe equals operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804028/106261) stops any type conversion.