# What can I use instead of typeof in JS

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic, typeof

If I have javascript array with objects inside, something like this

```
articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded
```

If I try do this:

```
if ( typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded != 'undefined' && ...) {
    // do something...
}
```

I have encountered with problem that if articleParams[itemId].properties is undefined I got an error: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined.

So in this case I should do something stupid like this:

```
if ( typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties != 'undefined' &&  
        typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded != 'undefined'  && ...) {
    // do something...
}
```

Is any equivalent in javascript like in PHP isset() ?

Comment: Yes there is an equivalent, `typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties == 'undefined'`.

Comment: The `phpjs` project has an implementation of [`isset`](http://phpjs.org/functions/isset/) for Javascript. If that is really what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually getting an error because `articlesParams[itemId]` is undefined, not because `properties` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry guys, I found a typo in my question: articlesParams[itemId].properties == 'undefined'

supposed to be: articlesParams[itemId].properties != 'undefined' (already corrected)

Comment: But question still the same and not resolved

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to just do this, which is quite typical in JS:

```
if (articlesParams[itemId] &&
    articlesParams[itemId].properties &&  
    articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded  && ...) {
    // do something...
}
```

or this:

```
var item = articlesParams[itemId];
if (item && item.properties && item.properties.loaded  && ...) {
    // do something...
}
```

One point to note is that this will not work if you want the `if` statement to execute even if `loaded` is `false`. In that case, you would be better off checking if it is `undefined` using `typeof`.

Comment: And if `item` is `undefined`, what does `item.properties` do?

Comment: @Xotic750 It would produce an error. If there's a chance it could be undefined, you could also add `item` to the `if` condition.

Comment: Yes, it was just a note as OP said `Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined.` ;)

Comment: One further note about the note, possibly use a positive check instead of check for `undefined`, then do `if (item && item.properties && item.properties.loaded === true && ...) {` or something similar `=== false`, whatever fills the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Although verbose, **the standard JavaScript idiom for checking whether a variable is undefined does use `typeof`** and in fact looks much like what you wrote.  There is no separate JavaScript equivalent to PHP's `isset()`.

Only two minor improvements to offer:

- [Use `!==` rather than `!=` with `typeof`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3804005/290085)
- Define new variables for expressions you'll be re-using.

Like this:

```
var item = articlesParams[itemId];
if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
   var props = item.properties;
   if (typeof props !== 'undefined') {
       var loaded = props.loaded;
       if (typeof loaded !== 'undefined') {
           // do something...
       }
   }
}
```

Of course, if `loaded`, `props`, etc aren't re-used much, there's little motivation for defining vars for them.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, you could just chain lots of typeof expressions. Alternatively....

```
var result;
try {
   result=typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded;
} catch(e) {
   result='undefined';
}
if ('undefined'==result) {
    // do something
}
```

But there's a risk that you might apply this to a method rather than a variable and hence it should throw a different kind of exception. Further, it can't simply be wrapped up as a function (since the exception will occur when you try to call the function, and not in the function body). And there's little savings in the amount of typing you need to do or the ease of understanding what the code does compared to chained typeof expressions.

It may be more appropriate to do simply do this:

```
try {
   typeof articlesParams[itemId].properties.loaded;
} catch (e) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: While I do this kind of thing when feature/bug detecting, I don't think that I would use it in the main running of my code. But a solution. :)

Comment: try{typeof a.b.c.d.e.f} catch(e){'undefined'} – this will never cause an exception, and seems to be the most terse way to see if a deep object exists. If the object doesn't exist then it will always return 'undefined'