# Advantages of "string" === "string" with typeof

Tags: javascript, string, types, parameters, equality

In Javascript `===` compares type as well as value, where as `==` just compares value. In the following example, is there any advantage of using `===` over `==`?

```
function roll( sides ){
    if ( typeof sides === "undefined" ) {
        sides = 6;
    }
    var result = Math.random() ;
    result = result * sides ;
    result = Math.floor(result) ;
    return result ;
};
```

According to the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) documentation it will only ever return a string. This leads me to believe utilizing `===` doesn't offer any advantages in this situation.

I imagine whoever wrote the tutorial I am following used `===` out of habit?

Comment: Answered through CodeCaster's comment link.
[What's the reason to use === instead of == with typeof in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804005/whats-the-reason-to-use-instead-of-with-typeof-in-javascript)

Comment: `==` compares type as well. It's how they react when the types don't match that makes them different.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, `===` might give you a tiny (usually negligible) performance benefit over `==`.

It's also safer to use `===`, precisely because it also tests if type is identical.

For example, consider this :

- `TRUE === 1` and `FALSE === 0` both are `FALSE`
- `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0` both are `TRUE`.

In most cases, you want the former and not the latter behavior.

Comment: When the types match, there should be no performance difference.

Comment: @LyeFish : I'd love to see some benchmarks for that :-)

Comment: Just look at the algorithms they use. When the types match, the algorithms are identical. Of course there could always be browser irregularities due to certain optimizations, but that can work either way.

Comment: @LyeFish : Well, I've always understood that `===` is always *slightly* faster than `==` because `==` does check for type whereas `===` can just skip that check. Are you saying that information is incorrect?

Comment: They both start with the same type check of both operands. If the types match, the algorithm is the same. When the types don't match, the `===` returns `false` immediately, whereas the `==` continues on to a part of the algorithm that coerces one of the operands, and recursively re-enters the original algorithm until the types match.

Comment: [Here's the algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) used by `==` and [here's the one](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) used by `===`. Notice they both begin with the same type check, and if the types match, the subsequent steps in both cases are identical.

Comment: @LyeFish : Makes sense. I updated my answer. Thx for the info!